# What does "at the other end" mean?

Tags: prepositions, british-english

I learn English from New Headway elementary book. In Unit 4 p.136, there is a sentence:

> There's a fire at the other end.

I feed confuse the meaning of **at the other end**. How can I understand the meaning of idea that this sentence express?

Many thanks.

Comment: It isn't clear without context. There might be a room, a road, a stick, or some other object being discussed, and the fire is at the other end from the speaker.

Comment: You need to know where (and on what) the fire is. Or use "at the other end *of (something)*".

Comment: Yes, I understand it isn't clear but the book only provides exact the sentence. How about `There's a fire at the other end of the street` mean?

Comment: Please provide the *context* - at least some text before and after the text you are asking about. As it stands, any answer would be a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrase “at the other end” implies the context that there is something with two recognisable ends, such as a corridor, a street, a candle or a length of rope. It also implies that the focus of attention is at one end - for example, both speaker and listener might be at the South end of a corridor that runs North-South.

“The other end” then refers to the end not previously focused on. So if the focus (whether express or implied) was on the South end, the *other* end would be the North end. By *implied* focus, I’m referring to situations such as the following: a fireman breaks down the front door to an apartment at the South end of a corridor, and shouts to the person inside that here is a fire at “the other end” of the corridor. Although the fireman didn’t actually say, “We are at this end” or “We are at one end”, the physical and very obvious location of both speaker and listener would be understood to be “this end”.

Example: one end of a candle has an exposed wick. The other end is flat.